# disable wp-pagenavi on pages with template using the wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

How can i disable wp-pagenavi on pages using templates and the wordpress loop? It seems that wp-pagenavi adds itself automatically wherever the wordpress loop is used, not counting that it is a page or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad..the *theme* called wppagenavi(), thus pagenavi is not added automagically.

By removing that call from templates of choice i can achieve what i wanted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the function call out off it

Comment: it is added automatically by the plugin and not manually by me.

Comment: Its a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/), so disable it at your plugins